# Redirect URLS to subfolder

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, redirect

I'm an iOS dev mainly but I'm trying to figure this out. How can I make any variation like example.com/page/23920 redirect to example.com/page/?

I am storing IDs passed from my app into URLs in the format:
**example.com/page/12345**

and what I want to do is read the ID value from the URL. I'm new to web development, and I don't understand how get these randomly generated pages setup--right now all the pages don't exist on my server and so they are all 404s.

In my .htaccess file I was trying:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^page/$1 /page/? [L,R=301]
```

I still get the error that the resulting page was not found on the server.

Comment: Have you tried specific anything already?

Comment: Please show us your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Question is unclear without provided rules.

Answer (score -1):

usually, url pattern such as example.com/page/23920 is actually some controller actions such as actionPage($id). In this case 23920 is the id. So it is very easy if you go to the function specified in router file, then you can simply do ( just an example)

```
public function actionPage($id){
    //codes to check if id is present
    ....

    if($id==null){
        header("Location: /page");
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: wow, my answer is not useful...and get downvoted...and why not useful?

Comment: Not the downvoter, but the OP hasn't given enough information to tell if your answer would fit

Comment: Could you explain where this function is called?